# How to convert my own dataset into x_train y _train , x_test x_train

Tags: keras

I have separate folders for training and validation, each containing three sub folders (normal, happy,surprise ) . Training 6000 samples and validation 2000 samples .

After reading all the data from each folder and converting into train_img_data and val_img_data variables , how I can convert them into x_train y_train and x_test and y_test for fitting the network ?

Can someone help me with this issue
Thank you so much in advance ....

Comment: "After reading all the data from each folder and **converting** them into train_img_data and val_img_data..." So what exactly did you convert your data to, if not `x_train` and `y_train`? Or in other words: what is the type of `train_img_data` and `val_img_data`? Best would be to show those parts of your code that create them.

Answer (score 0):

Use can use `train_test_split` function from `sklearn`. See [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html).

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

data = []
labels = []
# suppose you've loaded your data and labels

# partition the data into training and testing splits using 80% of
# the data for training and the remaining 20% for testing
(trainX, testX, trainY, testY) = train_test_split(data, labels, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood you correctly but if you want to use the **train_img_data** as the training set and the **val_img_data** as the data set on which you want to compute the performance metrics (for example MSE in case of regression, accuracy, F1 score in case of classification) then assuming you want to get predictions for column named **targetColumn** you could just do:

```
x_train = train_img_data.drop(columns=['targetColumn'])
y_train = train_img_data['targetColumn']
x_test = val_img_data.drop(columns=['targetColumn'])
y_test = val_img_data['targetColumn']
```

EDIT:
I haven't spotted the *keras* tag on this question - I was assuming here the train_img_data and val_img_data are Pandas DataFrames